# get X,Y coords of an isometric cell by its id

Tags: java, isometric

[image]

I have an isometric grid that is numbered like the image above. I need a function that returns X,Y coords from a given cell number, without using any kind of `loops`.

I've literally spent hours trying to figure this out, here is what I came up with so far:

```
public static Coords getXY(int cellID)
{       
    final double CELL_WIDTH     = 53;
    final double LEVEL_HEIGHT   = 27;
    final int gridWidth         = 6;

    boolean isYellowRow = cellID % (gridWidth*2-1) <= gridWidth;        

    double x = ((cellID % gridWidth) + 1) + (isYellowRow ? 0 : 0.5 );

    double y = cellID / (gridWidth*2-1);
    y = Math.round(y) + (isYellowRow ? 1 : 0);

    System.out.println(x+", "+y);

    x *= CELL_WIDTH;
    y *= LEVEL_HEIGHT;

    System.out.println(x+", "+y);

    return Coords(x, y);
}
```

It's messy not working and isn't complete yet, I'v spent way more time than I should on this and I'm still unable to solve it, so I'm asking your help please.

Some examples of expected results:

```
getXY(1); // Should return: 53, 27
getXY(2); // Should return: 106, 27
getXY(6); // Should return: 26.5, 40.5 (40.5 is because +=cellHeight/2..)
getXY(7); // Should return: 79.5, 40.5
getXY(12); // Should return: 53, 54
```

Comment: What is it returning currently?

Comment: XY coordinates of _what_? Relative to _what_? What does the coordinate grid look like?  The question is meaningless without this information.

Comment: if the id is unique you can just use a map.

Comment: @JimGarrison XY relative to the grid in the example image. There's an example of expected results that gives an idea. Doesn't have to be precise, i'll tweak it later.

Comment: So (0,0) is the very top-left pixel of the entire image, and the X and Y units are pixels, and the coordinates of a "cell" represent the position of its top vertex?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
int n;         // cell number
double x, y;   // coordinates of top vertex of cell
double CELL_WIDTH = 53;
double LEVEL_HEIGHT = 27;

x = (double)(((n-1)%11) * CELL_WIDTH) - (((n-1)%11 > 4) ? 5.5d*CELL_WIDTH : 0d);
y = (double)((n-1)/11) * LEVEL_HEIGHT * 2d + (((n-1)%11 > 4)  ? LEVEL_HEIGHT/2  : 0d);
```

This places (0,0) at the top vertex of the first cell.  Add offsets to move (0,0) wherever you want it to be.

The approach:

The repetitive pattern has period 11, in two rows.  So, first calculate the horizontal offset as if the 11 cells were in a straight line: `((n-1)%11) * CELL_WIDTH`. Then realize that if the cell is on the second line, the horizontal offset will be left by 5-1/2 cells: `- ((n-1)%11 > 4) ? 5.5d*CELL_WIDTH : 0d`.  Do the same for the vertical offsets and throw in appropriate casting so the result is floating point (since you seem to want half-pixel answers).

Comment: The last line is missing a little parenthesis after the '+' sign.
Thank you so much, I am testing it right now and it seems to work! Will do some more testings and tweakings and get back to you. Thank you!